# WP8 How to change radiobutton checked visual state color?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am having a problem dealing with the dark theme on WP8, the checked (dot) radiobutton isn't showing. The same radiobuttons works fine on both themes on WP7 but I can't find a way to change the color of selected radiobutton on WP8; is there a way of doing it on c#? 
I don't want to to over blend and change the checked visual state...

Comment: Unless you've got a really good reason for why you "don't want" to style the control's checked state, that's the intended method for accomplishing your goal and should be how you approach the problem.

Comment: After created the Radio Btn. Change the brush of the particular radio btn(i.e:Background , Foreground, border). and also check it for Dark/Light theme in Vs2012 for windows phone 8.

Comment: I though it would be a different approach for WP8 because we don't have to worry about it on WP7. Anyway I have created a new style on Blend, and changed <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" .../> to <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="Black" .../> now I can see the checkmark on dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the checked color of the radiobutton is to override the control template. You can made a copy of the original or current template and only modify the checked element color.